# Looking for Balas' original JSP-as-digraph paper

Tags: graphs, job-shop-scheduling, journals

I'm looking for E. Balas' original paper "Finding a Minimaximal Path in a Disjunctive PERT Network". Is this paper available via the web? Google and my campus library are unable to help me find a copy of this paper. It appears that it was originally published in a French journal, and I speak no French. Is the paper even in English?

My purpose in looking for it: it is common now to represent job-shop problems as disjunctive graphs, with $C_{max}$ as its minimax path. But how does one prove that the two representations are equivalent?

Comment: Full citation:  E. Balas, "Finding a Minimaximal Path in a Disjunctive PERT Network," Thérie des Graphes, _Journeés Internationales d'Etudes_, Rome, 1966, Dunod, Paris 1967. ([source](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1147/rd.134.0391))